# Can we use the modal verb "could" to give permission?

Tags: modal-verbs, conversation

Can we use the modal verb "could" to give permission?

For example:

> Mr A: Could I take your car?
>
> Mr B: Yes you could.

Comment: No, Mr. B should say 'Yes, you can'. He might say 'You could if I had it with me today, but it's in the garage for repairs,'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, it's not entirely natural, and it normally requires more context than given in the question.

For instance:

> Mr. A: "I know you don't normally allow people to drive your car, but if I grab you that food you need, could I take your car?"
>
> Mr. B: "Yes, you could."

In that context, it's made clear from the preceding context that *could* is associated with permission. Also note that the sentence was converted into a conditional (which makes *could* more natural).

These are all things that could be given in previous sentences too:

> Mr. A: "You don't normally let people take your car do you?"
>
> Mr. B. "No."
>
> Mr. A. "But I know you need some groceries and, because you hurt your leg, you can't drive yourself. So, if I picked those up for you …"
>
> Mr. B. "Yes?"
>
> Mr. A. "Could I take your car?"
>
> Mr. B. "Yes, you could."

---

More often, the person asking the question would simply say (without any of that additional context), "*Can* I take your car?" and the person answering would say, "Yes, you *can*" or "Yes, you *may*."

Even if the question is asked with *could*, the answer more commonly comes backs with *can* or *may*.

---

However, especially in formal English, some people will mirror back the word used.

For instance, even though it isn't typical, it's perfectly possible to hear an exchange like this:

> "Might I have some of that mustard?"
>
> "Why, yes, you might."

It's a form of exaggerated speech that's most often used as a kind of old-fashioned, upper-class affectation.